# Facebook php-sdk v4 PhalconPHP integration

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, phalcon

I'm currently trying to integrate the lastest Facebook php sdk into a Phalcon project but I'm not having much luck.

I can get the SDK to work in a standalone project but the exact same code fails when integrated into a Phalcon project (either as a service or directly in a Controller).

The issue seems to be that the facebook redirect helper creates a "state" property which is appended to a loginUrl and then stored in a session. When a user is redirected back to my site after signing in, it checks this property against a querystring value. The state property is only generated and stored whenever you display the login url via the redirectHelpers getLoginUrl() method. Somehow, when I integrate this in Phalcon the session variable and the $_GET parameter never seem to match up. The simple example which works is as follows

```
 // lots of requires
 Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($appId,$secret);
 $helper = new Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/');
 // see if a existing session exists
 if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
  // create new session from saved access_token
      $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

  // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
  try {
         if ( !$session->validate() ) {
         $session = null;
   }
  } catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // catch any exceptions
        $session = null;
    }
   }  // end if isset($_SESSION)

 if ( !isset( $session ) || $session === null ) {
  // no session exists

  try {
          $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
   } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
     // handle this better in production code
      print_r( $ex );
    } catch( Exception $ex ) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
     // handle this better in production code
       print_r( $ex );
          }
       }

   // see if we have a session
   if ( isset( $session ) ) {

    // save the session
     $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
     // create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
       $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

        // graph api request for user data
        $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
         $response = $request->execute();
          // get response
        $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

         // print profile data
            echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';

              // print logout url using session and redirect_uri (logout.php page should destroy the session)
               echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://yourwebsite.com/app/logout.php' ) . '">Logout</a>';
      } else {
    // show login url
      echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_friends' ) ) . '">Login</a>'; // this line would generate a new state
     }
```

When I try using this exact same code in a controller in a phalcon project (or by setting "$me" up in the $di), the state check always fails even though I'm not generating a new login url. The only other difference is that in the simple project I require all the facebook files using require_once but in the Phalcon project I use

```
$loader->registerNamespaces(
    array(
      "Facebook"    => __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/'
     )
  );
```

but replacing that with the requires doesn't seem to have an effect.

Anyone got any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked this one out. The issue was that the browser was automatically making a request to /favicon.ico as well,as I didn't have a favicon.ico this then rendered the default indexAction again and as such this was causing the getLoginUrl() method to fire again generating a new state. The simple fix is to just create a favicon, or define the error handling route for files not there (I was just using the boilerplate from the phalcon dev tools initially)

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working by using registerClasses not registerNamespaces - but using v3.2.x so not a v4.

```
$loader->regeisterNamespaces( /* Projects' classes */ )
    ->registerClasses(array(
        'Facebook' => __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/facebook/php-sdk/src/facebook.php'
    ))
    ->register();
```

ps.: Im using composer to load FacebookSDK so I have different path than yours.

Then I'm using it in Controller ordinary without using $di,

```
protected function getFacebook()
{
    if (!$this->facebook) {
        $this->facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => $this->config->social->facebook->appId,
            'secret' => $this->config->social->facebook->secret,
            'fileUpload' => false,
            'allowSignedRequest' => false,
        ));
    }
    return $this->facebook;
}
```

Comment: I'm using Composer as well. Are you definitely using v4 of the SDK? I'm not in a position to try this out at the moment,but do you set everything up as a service in the $di so it's available across all your controllers? Do you mind posting a bit of code about your implementation? thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer - but it turns out that I'm using v3.2 not v4.x. I think that v3.2 should be easily implemented as `$di` shared .component

Comment: Ah yeah, I had it all working with the older version of the SDK similar to that, the problem seems to only occur with the new version. Thanks for taking the time to answer though